# Dynamic content with cache manifest

Tags: php, jquery, caching, cache-manifest

I'm facing several challenges building a web app with cache manifest.

My challenge is dealing with dynamic content.  If a user logs out and logs back into the app with a **different** account, how can I deal with **reloading** the cached files to display the information relevant to the users account?

Is it possible to force reset/reload the cache manifest?  Documentation appears to be slim.

I'm building the app on jQuery Mobile and Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Have never done this but first line of thinking is set up query params in manifest attribute url.

```html
<html manifest="manifestFileName.manifestMime?user_id=1234&version=xxx">
```

Then use `htaccess` to redirect any requests for `.manifestMime` to a php file that outputs appropriate user resources.

Would have to have a segment in url for html output pages that makes url unique per account and if viable could even add a set of links for `my Accounts`

An alternative manifest naming protocol could be something like:

```
<html manifest="manifestFileName.USER_ID.manifestMime">
```